# R: Getting links from Google search results beyond the first page r

Tags: r

I have this `RSelenium` setup (using selenium really shouldn't impact the answer to this question):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
library(httr)
library(RSelenium) # running through docker

## RSelenium setup
remDr <- remoteDriver(port = 4445L, browserName = "chrome")
remDr$open()

## Navigate to Google Books 
remDr$navigate("https://books.google.com/")
books <- remDr$findElement(using = "css", "[name = 'q']")

## Search for whatever, the Civil War, for example
books$sendKeysToElement(list("the civil war", key = "enter"))

## Getting Google web elements (10 per page)
bookElem <- remDr$findElements(using = "xpath", "//h3[@class = 'LC20lb']//parent::a")

## Click on each book link
links <- sapply(bookElem, function(bookElem){
  bookElem$getElementAttribute("href")
})
```

This works great - and compiles all of the links from the first page of results (Google automatically limits it to 10 results, so ten links). What I would like is to have that same `links` vector compile every result link from the first, say, 12 pages (to keep it manageable). So:

```
goog_pgs <- seq(1:12) # to set the limit
```

Where I'm lost: how do I feed that into my `links` vector? The links from each page are too different and aren't simple enough to just feed the number to its end. I've tried inserting the following:

```
nextButton <- remDr$findElements("xpath", "//*[@id = 'pnnext']")
next_page <- sapply(nextButton, function(nextButton) {
  next_elements$clickElement()
})
```

And that does not work. What's the solution here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the sequence `1:12` as something to iterate over, using a `for` loop, `lapply`, or other looping mechanism. I have a terrible time with the `apply` functions, so I swapped in with `map`. The steps that need to be done repeatedly are finding books, getting the `href` of each book, and clicking the "next" button. With some modification, you can use:

```
books_12 <- map(1:12, function(pg) {
  bookElem <- remDr$findElements(using = "xpath", "//h3[@class = 'LC20lb']//parent::a")
  links <- map_chr(bookElem, ~.$getElementAttribute("href")[[1]])

  nextButton <- remDr$findElement("xpath", "//*[@id='pnnext']")
  nextButton$clickElement()

  links
})
```

Note that `getElementAttribute` returns a list; since each element only has one `href`, I kept the first (only) one with `[[1]]`. This yields a list of 12 vectors of 10 URLs each.

Comment: This is awesome. Will implement in the coming days. Question: the `pg` does not get used within the function itself? Out of curiosity, why is that? Is it because the `pg` is simply not needed and functions as a placeholder?

Comment: Yeah in this case there wasn't a need for it. There might be situations where, you need that index, such as if you didn't have access to a "next" button and had to go through the pages by number